# Bubble Sort (or Similar) Excel VBA with single and multivariable criteria: Solve for lowest sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Long time lurker first time poster.

I'm working on an Excel project to solve for the best (lowest value) combination of vendors and achieve full criteria coverage. The exercise is fairly simple for 95% of cases.

In the other 5% of cases I need to account for situations where vendors may be covering multiple criteria.

I understand usage of bubble sort when each vendor covers one criteria but I'm stumped when it comes to the combo criteria. I have scoured the web and haven't had much luck. Admittedly this could be a result of improper search terminology on my part.

For example the data could look like this:

[image: Example Data]

In this example the proper solution would be the sum of Test 1 (A) & Test 6 (B, C, D) as this achieves full criteria coverage and returns the lowest value.

I'm not looking for code examples, but rather some conceptual guidance on how to tackle the challenge.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's a rabbit hole, but I think what you are looking for is constraint optimization in  operation research. The question is how big is your data set? For a small data set (maybe slightly bigger than what you are showing) Excel's Solver may give an answer, but I've seen it choke too many times to deem it useful. Using VBA to brute force this will also quickly get bogged down as each new row or column added potentially increases the number of computations factorially (is that even a word) instead of exponentially. Good luck.

Comment: @gns100 Wow, that is a rabbit hole! I'll start digging into that. My data set will be relatively small, say 120 vendors and 30 criteria. I think your suggestion to brute force it may be a good path, as the number of vendors with combo criteria will be low.  I'll run some tests. Thank you for the input.

Comment: With C criteria and V vendors your optimal solution will have no more than C vendors. You have to consider at maximum 2^C vendors, the best of each type (If you have 2 vendors that both covers both A and B you will consider only the lower value one, the _champion_ of his type). Then you can build all the solutions with up to C available champions that cover all the criteria, you may order them by value etc etc... But why bubble sort?

Comment: @Hastur Thanks for the insight. No particular reason for bubble sort. I'm effectively a hobbyist with VBA and a sorting algorithm is outside my current wheelhouse. After some research bubble sort popped up as an option for the vendors with individual criteria, so I've been using that as my basis of design. Once I have some code working for the task I'll post the solution in the event anyone out there is interested.

Answer (score 0):

An example of brute force solution. In this case it requires 3*4*3*3 = 108 loops. Number of 30 criteria seems to me very big.

```
Sub FindOpt()
    Dim A, B, C, D
    A = Array(1, 5, 7)
    B = Array(2, 5, 6, 8)
    C = Array(3, 6, 8)
    D = Array(4, 6, 7)
    Dim Totals
    ReDim Totals(1 To 8) As Double
    Totals(1) = 1.5: Totals(2) = 2.5: Totals(3) = 3.5: Totals(4) = 4.5
    Totals(5) = 2.25: Totals(6) = 7#: Totals(7) = 4.25: Totals(8) = 4.5
   
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long
    Dim Res, MinTot As Double, Tot As Double, el, MinRes
    MinTot = 100#
    For i = 0 To UBound(A)
        For j = 0 To UBound(B)
            For k = 0 To UBound(C)
                For m = 0 To UBound(D)
                    Res = RemDup(A(i), B(j), C(k), D(m))
                    Tot = 0#
                    For Each el In Res
                        Tot = Tot + Totals(el)
                    Next el
                    If Tot < MinTot Then
                        MinTot = Tot
                        MinRes = Res
                    End If
    Next m, k, j, i
    MsgBox "The best combination" & vbLf & "Total cost " & MinTot & _
        vbLf & "Vendors: " & Join(MinRes, ", ")
End Sub

Private Function RemDup(ParamArray list())
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(list) To UBound(list)
        On Error Resume Next
        coll.Add CStr(list(i)), CStr(list(i))
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
    Dim Res
    ReDim Res(1 To coll.Count) As String
    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        Res(i) = coll(i)
    Next i
    RemDup = Res
End Function
```